# org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring-cloud, consul

I am facing below error when trying to compile project from the link: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-cloud/consul-service-registration-discovery/. I am just running **spring-cloud-consul-student** without any customization facing below error. All code shown below for refernce.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project spring-cloud-consul-student: Compilation
>   failure: Compilation failure:
>       [ERROR] /C:/Users/pashtikar/Documents/MyELC/spring-cloud-consul-student/src/main/java/com/example/howtodoinjava/SpringCloudConsulStudentApplication.java:[5,50]
>   package org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery does not exist
>       [ERROR] /C:/Users/pashtikar/Documents/MyELC/spring-cloud-consul-student/src/main/java/com/example/howtodoinjava/SpringCloudConsulStudentApplication.java:[8,2]
>   cannot find symbol
>       [ERROR]   symbol: class EnableDiscoveryClient
>       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>       org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project spring-cloud-consul-student: Compilation
>   failure
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute
>   (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
>       Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure

**SpringCloudConsulStudentApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpringCloudConsulStudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConsulStudentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9098
spring.application.name=student-service
management.security.enabled=false
```

**StudentServiceController**

```
@RestController
public class StudentServiceController {
    private static Map<String, List<Student>> schooDB = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();

    static {
        schooDB = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();

        List<Student> lst = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student std = new Student("Sajal", "Class IV");
        lst.add(std);
        std = new Student("Lokesh", "Class V");
        lst.add(std);

        schooDB.put("abcschool", lst);

        lst = new ArrayList<Student>();
        std = new Student("Kajal", "Class III");
        lst.add(std);
        std = new Student("Sukesh", "Class VI");
        lst.add(std);

        schooDB.put("xyzschool", lst);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getStudentDetailsForSchool/{schoolname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Student> getStudents(@PathVariable String schoolname) {
        System.out.println("Getting Student details for " + schoolname);

        List<Student> studentList = schooDB.get(schoolname);
        if (studentList == null) {
            studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            Student std = new Student("Not Found", "N/A");
            studentList.add(std);
        }
        return studentList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your pom is more important here than your code

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1.Follow below steps:- Window --> Preference --> Installed JREs -->Change path of JRE to JDK(add). Also make sure the jdk version in your POM is same as that of java compiler you have.

2.Did you check the directory path in which your project is located. May be it has access restrictions.

3.Check your internet connection, whether you are able to reach https://repo.spring.io .